# How do I connect through university's VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, networkmanager, fedora-18

I have a very high ping on my internet connection to international game servers and I was told a VPN connection should do some trick to try to lower it. That said, I found my university has a public VPN service and got an account for it.

I am very inexperient with this and cannot configure the VPN connection correctly. With the correct settings (at least protocol, server, username and password are correct and I set to use Google's public DNS), I cannot connect. NetworkManager just tells me "fail to connect" with no apparent misconfiguration.

Also, I shall note that "pinging" my router using the VPN server (via SSH) gives me very unconsistent values:

```
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 8.579/183.883/494.535/121.183 ms
```

While pinging the destination gives always very near 146ms (with less than 0.5ms maximum deviation) but I just guess it's fine.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: As the tags say, Fedora 18

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting from the command line. You may have to run this command as a root user (to create the "tun" device). Replace the configuration as required:

```
/usr/sbin/openvpn --remote vpnserver.example.com --nobind --dev tun --proto tcp-client --port 1194 --cipher BF-CBC --auth-nocache --syslog nm-openvpn --script-security 2 --up /usr/libexec/nm-openvpn-service-openvpn-helper --up-restart --persist-key --persist-tun --client --ca /path/vpnserver.ca --cert /path/client.crt --key /path/client.key
```

For the last 3 parameters, they are the server's Root CA certificate, your client's certificate and client's private key file. These should have been provided to you by the VPN administrator.

Comment: Oh, they are not provided. They only provide a quick tutorial for using VPN service in Windows. In fact, even the ftp server has no certificate to download and FileZilla asks me if I want to use the one the server provides.

Comment: In that case, are they providing a .ovpn file for Windows users to download and use? If it is, you can also use that to try:
    /usr/sbin/openvpn --config myconfig.ovpn

Comment: No, they don't, I have only the IP

Comment: What are the exact instructions for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

If you're connecting from within your University's network, chances are, you will not be able to connect to the VPN.

Generally a VPN is a way of virtually connecting to a remote network to perform tasks as if your computer was connected directly, if however you are already inside that network, you shouldn't need to nor be able to connect.

If you are experiencing high latency when gaming, a VPN would not be the route to take.

Comment: I'm connecting from home (so obviously outside university :P). Well, I said VPN but in the end I want a tunneling service, don't them work?